# curl: (1) Protocol "ldap" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: 16.04, curl

How can I enable ldap protocol in curl?

```
root@gis-devel:~/curl-7.47.0# curl -V
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

Comment: FYI I have a standard `curl` package installed, no LDAP on my server or anywhere in the network, yet LDAP is listed in the protocols. Perhaps reinstall curl?

Comment: I notice you have OpenSSL support built in - did you compile `curl` from source?

Comment: yes, I compiled curl from source, but I cant find out how to add ldap flag during compilation.

Comment: Then I suggest you recompile it with `--enable-ldap`. Apparently, this is not the default.